# CopyArtifacts(...) giving error when used within job-dsl-plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I tried using the CopyArtifacts() as well as writing a custom configure block for copying artifacts from upstream build. I get the errors in both as shown below -

```
FATAL: No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.Job.CopyArtifacts() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, jobDSL$_run_closure1_closure4_closure14) values: [xxx-StarTrooper-master.unity, target/**, jobDSL$_run_closure1_closure4_closure14@a1994b]
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.Job.CopyArtifacts() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String, jobDSL$_run_closure1_closure4_closure14) values: [xxx-StarTrooper-master.unity, target/**, jobDSL$_run_closure1_closure4_closure14@a1994b]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
    at jobDSL$_run_closure1_closure4.doCall(jobDSL.groovy:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

My code snippet is as below -

```
CopyArtifacts(downstreamUnityJob.name,'target/**'){ 
    buildNumber("${UNITY_BUILD_NUMBER}") 
}
```

When I try a custom configure block I get error as well -

```
FATAL: No signature of method: groovy.util.Node.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [xxx-StarTrooper-master.unity]
Possible solutions: wait(), name(), value(), any(), wait(long), get(java.lang.String)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.Node.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [xxx-StarTrooper-master.unity]
Possible solutions: wait(), name(), value(), any(), wait(long), get(java.lang.String)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at jobDSL$_run_closure1_closure4_closure14_closure16.doCall(jobDSL.groovy:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

and here is my configure block -

```
configure {
    project -> project/ builders / 'hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifact'{
        projectName downstreamUnityJob.name //downstreamUnityJob comes from another job dsl object 
        project downstreamUnityJob.name
        filter 'target/**'
        selector('class':"hudson.plugins.copyartifact.SpecificBuild"){
            buildNumber "$UNITY_BUILD_NUMBER"
        }
    }
}
```

Can you let me know what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

In the JobDsl, copyArtifacts needs to start with a lower case c (not upper case C as you have it)

See here [Job dsl wiki](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-DSL-Commands) and [StepContext.copyArtifacts](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.copyArtifacts)

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo. Even after fixing that I had a similar problem. I later figured out the problem though. The copyArtifacts(...) call needed to be under steps{ ... }

Comment: @b0s0nparticle88 : if u find the problem, answer it by yourself and marked answered

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I ran into the same issue.

```
  configure { project ->
    project / builders << 'hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifact' {
      project(value.deps.get(0))
      filter(value.ins)
      target('')
      buildChooser(class: 'hudson.plugins.copyartifact.SpecificBuildSelector') {
        buildNumber('${parentBuildNo}')
      }
      doNotFingerprintArtifacts(true)
    }
  }
```

resulted in a `FATAL: No signature of method: groovy.util.Node.call()` for me.

I solved it by changing the name of the XML element being modified from `project` to `myProject`. Since the `project` modifier in the configure block shadows the name of the element you are modifying, it's necessary to use a different name for the closure argument.

```
  configure { myProject ->
    myProject / builders << 'hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifact' {
      project(value.deps.get(0))
      filter(value.ins)
      target('')
      buildChooser(class: 'hudson.plugins.copyartifact.SpecificBuildSelector') {
        buildNumber('${parentBuildNo}')
      }
      doNotFingerprintArtifacts(true)
    }
  }
```

Success!

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, you should use the `delegate` attribute.

Your element might have a conflict with an other one.

Here is an example :

```
      configure { project ->
      project / builders << 'hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifact' {
        delegate.project 'BLABLA' // DELEGATE
        ...
     }
```